# In angular4 Js file not loading after routerLink

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack-dev-server

I am using `bootstrap-sweetalert` `js` and `css` files with `Angular 4` + `Webpack 3`.

When I (f5) refresh the URL in the browser the `SweetAlert` `js` is loading and on button click its `bootstrap-sweetalert` works fine but if I move to another route using `Angular 4` `[routerLink]` directives and come back to same URL at that time on button click its not working.

The issue is that the js file is not loading after `[routerLink]`.